# Set variable to reference another variable, Java

Tags: java

In Android Studio, I have two array lists with a custom object

```
ArrayList<MenuMaker> consessionlist = new ArrayList<MenuMaker>();
ArrayList<MenuMaker> entrylist = new ArrayList<MenuMaker>();
```

And have a few voids that depending on which mode we are in, it needs to use one ArrayList or the other:

```
private void createMenuButtons()
{
    int FoodSize = consessionlist.size();
    ...
```

I realize I could do an if statement that if mode = 0 use consessionlist, else use entrylist, but is there a way to say

```
private void setmode(mode)
{
     if (mode == 0){
        menulist = consessionlist;
     }
     else
     {
        menulist = entrylist;
     }
}
private void createMenuButtons()
{
    int FoodSize = menulist.size();
    ...
```

*Pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value seem to kick my butt on the Oracle test.

Comment: That is the correct way you are saying it, though an extra memory reference is getting created. You are assigning the list reference to other list, but I don't understand why you are confused with Pass by value or reference over here.

Comment: Nothing in Java is pass-by-reference.  The **trick** is that the value of an object's variable is *already* a reference (or `null`).  Passing a reference by value means that the variable is still a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would have to use an if statement overtime I need to choose or have to add some weird complexity, but thus far its actually working as I wanted it to.